# How can I prerender a page that will open in a new tab?

Tags: html

I'm trying to prerender a page that will open as a new tab (right now I'm using an `<a target="_blank">`). However, when I click on the link after it has prerendered, it doesn't work. When I take the `target` out, it works.

How can I have prerender work when I want the page to open as a new tab?

Here's some code I've tested with:

Doesn't work:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/">
    Test 1
    <link rel="prerender" href="http://example.com/">
</a>
```

Works:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/">
    Test 2
    <link rel="prerender" href="http://example.com/">
</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean prerender a page that opens in new tab? new tab will load from beginning.

Comment: see 'prefetch' : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching

Comment: @user1533609 I mean that when I click on an `<a target="_blank">`, I want to prerender the page that will open, similar to how it works in my second code snippet. @Milche That's what I'm trying to use, but it doesn't work.